# NodeJS, make HTTP GET request with http module, code does not show headers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple HTTP server (Apache default webpage) running on `127.0.0.1:5000`. I would like to write a NodeJS client which will make a HTTP GET request and read headers and the whole page content and prints it on client's side. Here's what I have:

```html
const http = require('http');

function check_server(url) {

    var options = {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 5000,
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var request = http.request(options, (res) => {
        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.error(`Did not get an OK from the server. Code: ${res.statusCode}`);
            res.resume();
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Connected, got code 200");
        }

        let data = '';

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Retrieved all data');
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });

    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`Encountered an error trying to make a request: ${err.message}`);
    });

}

check_server('http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
```

However, I don't see anything in console. I don't even know if its connecting. What's wrong? My NodeJS version is `v16.16.0`.

Comment: `http.request` is a *really* old and clunky API. Node 17.5 has native support for [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), and you can use a variety of third party packages with nicer APIs (such as  [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)) and I'd strongly recommend using one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to end your request.

It is still waiting, it isn't send, that is why the function hangs up.

```
    request.end();
```

```
function check_server(url) {

    var options = {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 5000,
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET'
    };

    var request = http.request(options, (res) => {
        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.error(`Did not get an OK from the server. Code: ${res.statusCode}`);
            res.resume();
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Connected, got code 200");
        }

        let data = '';

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Retrieved all data');
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });

    request.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`Encountered an error trying to make a request: ${err.message}`);
    });

    request.end();

}

check_server('http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
```